# python decorators and static methods

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to add decorator with my python static method, like following:

```
class AdminPanelModel(db.Model):

    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    visible = db.Column(db.Boolean,)


    def decor_init(func):
        def func_wrapper(*kargs, **kwargs):
            for l in model.all(): #internal logic
                pass

            return func(*kargs, **kwargs)

        return func_wrapper

    @staticmethod
    @decor_init
    def all_newscollection_at_adminpanel():
        pass
```

I tried adding `@staticmethod` to my decorator and tried to make function call like following `func(AdminPanelModel,*kargs, **kwargs)`, but no luck, still stuck at following error message:

```
TypeError: unbound method func_wrapper() must be called with AdminPanelModel instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Is there any way I can achieve that? I am aware of that there can be other way I can do the same work, but its more of an educational question rather than get things done somehow.

Comment: I'm sorry, but where do you getting `model` for `for l in model.all():`? And i think that you need to put decorator inside of your class.

Comment: that was part of internal logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `classmethod` instead:

```
@classmethod
@decor_init
def all_newscollection_at_adminpanel(cls):
    pass
```

The call is the same, but `classmethod`s implicitly receive the class as the first argument, which will then also be passed into the decorated function

to see the difference:

```
class AdminPanelModel(object):
    def decor_init(func):
        def func_wrapper(*kargs, **kwargs):
            print kargs    # The first element should be of type class AdminPanelModel
            return func(*kargs, **kwargs)

        return func_wrapper

    @staticmethod
    @decor_init
    def staticm():
        pass

    @classmethod
    @decor_init
    def classm(cls):
        pass
```

they yield

```
AdminPanelModel.staticm()
>>> ()                                      # empty, which is reason for error
AdminPanelModel.classm()
>>> (<class '__main__.AdminPanelModel'>,)   # class instance as first parameter
```

Comment: and what changes do I need to make on my decorator?

Comment: I believe you don't need to change anything. Are you seeing a new error message?

Comment: Thankyou, I needed to put `@classmethods` before `@decorator` which I was doing wrong initially. :)